# Implementing a Set Using a Sorted Array

Tags: c++, arrays, set

This is a data structures question, but also regarding implementation. A set is typically implemented using a BST, but my professor wants us to know how to implement some data structures when only given limited options. So he wants us to be able to understand how to create a set using only an array.

Using a standard (unsorted) array I understand the implementation/complexity...

```
void add(Student[] arr, Student findstu)
{
    Student stu = new Student();
    int i=0;
    boolean found = false;
    while(stu!=NULL)
    {
        stu = arr[i++];
        if (stu==findstu)
        {
             found = true;
        }
     }
    if (found==false)
    {
         arr[i+1] = findstu;
    }
 }
```

The add/remove/contains are ally pretty much the same code, all will have the first while loop, which will make them O(n).

But if we used a sorted array, why would contains be O(lgn) and add/remove O(n)?

Comment: That snippet is not valid (won't compile), and even if fixed is suboptimal

Comment: @Amit Can you expand on what you are saying? The idea here is not to have the best runtime...simply implement something given constraints

Comment: `Student stu = new Student();` is a syntax error since `stu` is not a pointer. It's suboptimal since you're allocating and initializing and object without ever needing it

Comment: It's also a memory leak, as you initialise a `Student` object on the heap and never delete it

Comment: I could just say `Student stu;` and that would be more appropriate right? I don't need to create an object on the heap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching would be of `O(logN)` because due to the fact that the array is sorted you could apply binary search which is of `O(logN)` complexity.

Insertion and erasure would be `O(N)` complexity (i.e., linear time) because every time you would attempt to insert or erase an element in the sorted array you would have to shift the elements of your array one position which is `O(N)` linear time complexity.